# Magento 2 new fieldset/field in cart price rule show unwanted Currently Active Tab

Tags: module, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2, price-rules

This is in my custom module xml `sales_rule_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="test_fieldset" sortOrder="10">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Fieldset</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="test_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Field</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

AND the it display in the backend like this:
[image]

See highlighted blue text 'Currently Active'  tracking this down it's coming from Native Magento xml at:

`../vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml`

and the xml is:

```
<fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="fieldset-schedule">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <label translate="true">Currently Active</label>
        </settings>
    </fieldset>
```

How, What ? anyone experience this?

Answer (score 0):

Because Magento Sales Rules `sale_rule_form.xml` general fielset doesn't have a `sortOrder` I am forced to add like this:

```
...
<fieldset name="general">
 <settings>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
 </settings>
</fieldset>
...
```

That way it will keep label/title at the top and the problem is sorted, Hooray!